# Run Hub Method directly in Controller Action by SignalR

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a SignalR something like below :

```
public class ConnectionHub : Hub
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, User> Users = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, User>();

    public void GetAddressingResult()
    {
         //some implementation
    }

}
```

I want to call GetAddressingResult method directly in an controller method.

```
    //In Home Controller

    [HttpPost]
    public void StartAddressing(string physicalAddress)
    {
        //I want to call GetAddressingResult method just here.
    }
```

I can do this now like calling javacsript method on the controller and the javascript calls the hub method. But it doesnt seem good. Also I tried to create an instance of a ConnectionHub in the controller action and call hub method than it gives me an error like "signalR hub instance outside of the hubpipleline"

I am using SignalR 1.1.4 version.

I am looking for a best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an instance of a hub- they are created as needed when hub methods are called.  See the following for how to call hub methods from outside the hub:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub